# How relate ReLU to Sigmoid

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Given a network,
input -> hidden layer with ReLU activation -> output layer with Sigmoid activation

I wonder how that can output values between 0 and 0.5, since ReLU returns positive values by definition, and a sigmoid is defined by 1/(1+e^-x), the smallest value would be 1/(1+e^-0) = 0.5

Is the sigmoid activation shifted or anything? Because I get output between 0 and 1 (as the manual says), but why?

Edit

here is a code snipped that prints the function output in the console , it shows what i expected: it starts with 0.5, and increases when x>0.

```py
    import numpy as np
    import tensorflow as tf
    
    x = np.array([x/10 for x in range(-20,20)])
    
    y = tf.keras.activations.sigmoid(
        tf.keras.activations.relu(x)
    )
    for a,b in zip(x,y):
        print(a,"\t",float(b))
```

output

```
-0.2     0.5
-0.1     0.5
0.0      0.5
0.1      0.52497918747894
0.2      0.549833997312478
0.3      0.574442516811659
0.4      0.5986876601124521
```

but if i do

```py
    x = Dense(64, activation="relu")(input)
    output = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)
```

I receive values between 0 and 1.

Comment: Have you tried to plot the functions?

Comment: There are a tonne of links on this - but try e.g. https://images.app.goo.gl/TBWdN8i8sLEEKhNo9

Comment: x can be negative, so as x -> `-inf` the function tends to 0. ReLU can also have a negative x - it just sets the output to zero below x = 0, which is why you might not think so.

Comment: yes, now i had printed the function and it does what i said, its 0.5 for x=0

Comment: Bias input.....?

Comment: i dont actively bias the input. maybe keras does that under the hood. that was my question.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it does apply a bias (`use_bias=True`) - but the default bias is zero, so you are OK there. https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/

Answer (score 1):

```
x = Dense(64, activation="relu")(input)
output = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)
```

Here, the output layer `x` is wrapped with the `ReLU` activation. So the output is a range from 0 to ∞
But when it is passed on to **layer** `output`, it is multiplied with weights (weights can be negative), whose output can be both negative & positive (therefore a range from -∞ to ∞). As the range is -∞ to ∞, passing it to the `sigmoid` function will give a value from 0 to 1

In conclusion, wrapping a `sigmoid` on `ReLU` will return a value in range 0.5 to ∞. And wrapping a `sigmoid` on top of a weighted `ReLU` will return a value in the range 0 to 1

Comment: thanks for that clarification. didnt knew there is a difference. unfortunatly that leads me to the question: then why is activation used at all, if it does not affect it ?

Comment: @343mps The input to the second layer is a function of the activation of the first AND the weights between that layer and the second layer. In general different activations will affect the second-layer inputs in different ways - as will the trained weights.

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong to apply Sigmoid on top of ReLU function. In implementation you seeing, probably output layer has its own weights which get multiplied to ReLU output. So theoretically sigmoid gets input between -inf to inf.

Comment: this cant be wrong since its used in most multi label classification models..

Comment: Ok maybe not wrong as such. But sigmoid works well when input is -inf to inf. So There must be a better activation function than sigmoid for a case where input is from 0 to inf (ReLUs range). Or maybe use a different activation function instead of two. Never seen anyone apply two activation function one after other.


Also do note that applying a dense layer with ReLU, then dense layer with sigmoid is not same as applying two activation function one after other (thats whole doubt OP has).

Answer (score 0):

In my research paper, I have used Sigmoid after Relu in the discriminator of a GAN architecture [Link to Github codebase](https://github.com/zaverichintan/Intention-based-Long-Term-Human-Motion-Anticipation/blob/master/ourgan/models/ourgan.py#L131C1-L136C25). Using Sigmoid after ReLU helped the training to converge quickly in my experiments.
Sigmoid after ReLU can be coded in PyTorch as following:

```
x = self.fc1(x)
x = F.relu(self.bn(x))
out = torch.sigmoid(x)
```

This helps in getting sigmoid output when input is greater than 0, and constant output of 0.5 when input is less than 0 (shifted ReLU 0->0.5).

I have attached the graphs for illustration:
[image: Plot showing Relu, Sigmoid and Relu+Sigmoid]